# ionic chat application using socket.io(how to make my user to join chat.socket.io)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, socket.io, chat

I am trying to do chat application using socket.io.

i have refereed this tutorila
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-socket-io-and-cordova-to-create-a-real-time-chat-app/

i am not able to get connected to the common server look here http://chat.socket.io/

> i would like to create an app where all the user enter the name and connect the chat.socket.io group. what is the server host they are using how can i connect my app users to join the chat.socket.io.

problem is i am not able to connect my users to http://chat.socket.io/

**UPDATE:**

**Lets say an example:**

> In my app i am having number of users and i have button called **chat**
>   when the user clicked the chat button he should enter this page http://chat.socket.io/ and i need a exit button to exit the chat
>
> To connect with server we need some thing like this "http://54.200.176.147:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js" is there any
>    port available for chat.socket.io please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather suggest you to setup your own server than trying to connect to http://chat.socket.io  You can setup your own server using nodejs and express and listen & broadcast chat messages.

Suggest you to check out this [socket io chat link](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for setting up the server and trying out basic chat. You can also download the server setup from my [github page](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Socket_IO_Server) and follow the chat link instruction to run the same which listens on port 3000. Hope it helps